# Looking for the Max Sum, based on Criteria and Unique Values

Tags: excel, sum, max, unique, criteria

```
Col1       Col2       Col3  
a          3          x  
b          2          x  
c          2          x  
a          1          x  
b          3          x  
c          1          y  
a          2          y  
b          1          y  
c          3          y
```

Using the table above, can anyone give me a formula to find:

The max sum of Col2 when Col3=X per each unique value in Col1

(Answer should be 5, would be 4 based on Col3=Y)

Comment: What language are you doing this in? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to do this in Excel.

Comment: I'm confused, why would it be 5? Unique max in col1 when col3 = X is a=3, b=3 and c=2 which = 8 in total. 5 (and 4 for Y) work if you want the min per unique.

Comment: Oh I think I get it now, take the max sum of unique Col1 & Col3 so for X its B which = 5 and for Y it's C which = 4?

Comment: pnuts is correct.  Anyway to do this without a pivot table?  I'm trying to repeat this for many different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable with `Col3` as FILTERS (select `x`), `Col1` for ROWS and Sum of `Col2` for VALUES. Uncheck Show grand totals for Columns and then for whichever column contains `Sum of Col2` take the maximum, say:

```
  =MAX(F:F)
```

Comment: I was trying to do this with a single formula and not a pivot table as I will be repeating this many times with different variables (x,y, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not ideal but it works:

Column D put an array formula in for Max If:

in D2: `=MAX(IF($C$2:$C$10=C2,SUM(IF($A$2:$A$10=A2,IF($C$2:$C$10=C2,$B$2:$B$10)))))`

Change the ranges obviously.

Then in E2 put this: `=MAX(IF($C$2:$C$10=C2,$D$2:$D$10))`

These are both array formulas so after inputting them you must press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER not just enter.

Then drag down.

There may be a way to combine these but my array formula knowledge is limited

Here are the results:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Sum of max per col 1    Max of col 4 per col 3
a       3       x       4                       5
b       2       x       5                       5
c       2       x       2                       5
a       1       x       4                       5
b       3       x       5                       5
c       1       y       4                       4
a       2       y       2                       4
b       1       y       1                       4
c       3       y       4                       4
```

If you don't use CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER you will get 18 and 5 all the way down.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was trying to do this without adding extra columns, but maybe this is the only way.